# Why should I use "extern" for function declaration in C?

Tags: c, extern

I was wondering if there is any difference if skip `extern` storage class specifier while declaring a function? Specifically, is there any difference between following two?

```
void foo ();
```

and

```
extern void foo();
```

Comment: Note that neither declaration is a prototype (in C).  Both declare a function that takes an indeterminate (but fixed) list of arguments, possibly including zero arguments.  It is not a 'variable length argument list' (varargs) function, though — it is not like `printf()` et al.  The story is different in C++; there the function is declared to take no parameters.

Comment: There's absolutely no point and no reason for using `extern` on function declarations. This is some archaic legacy habit, which has absolutely no value today.

Answer (score 2):

> *is there any difference between following two?*

Basically, no.

Each function declaration, is `extern` by default, (*i.e., in absence of any specific storage-class specifier*).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.2, *Linkages of identifiers*

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`.